# How do I assign a string to a variable using an anonymous function in the variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

```
var destURL = function () {
            if (this.typeOfDash == 'edit') {
                return '../../ajax/getParams.aspx';
            }
            else {
                return 'DashCreator.aspx';
            }
```

}

I was hoping that would work but it just assigns the function to the variable... I was hoping to get the returned value as the variables value... anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can evaluate the function immediatly to get the return value back.

```
var destURL = function () {
            if (this.typeOfDash == 'edit') {
                return '../../ajax/getParams.aspx';
            }
            else {
                return 'DashCreator.aspx';
            }
}()
```